# Visual studio 2022 perform search into .xsd designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xsd

I have a big project with an .xsd file that contains the dataset of all the tables of the database.
I use the .xsd designer integrated with visual studio to add query to table adapter and other stuff.

Due to the large amount of tables in the .xsd file is hard to locate a specific table, and i can't find a way to perform a search in this file; the common `ctrl+f` is doing nothing in this kind of file.

[image]

I've also tried to open the .xsd file with `XML Schema Explorer`, here i can perform a search, but i can't link back to the .xsd designer, because the search is performed in the xml schema.

[image]

Is there a way to perform a search in the .xsd designer?

Answer (score 2):

What version of visual studio are you using? in VS2022 there is a 'Show in Graph View' right click option in the XML Schema Explorer.

So you can use the search box in the explorer and then jump to it in the graph view?

[XML Schema Explorer right-click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/conKf.png)

Comment: I use VS2022 but my view is different from yours: [image](https://imgur.com/a/bhJ2c5w)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hmm. would you be willing to share a bit of your xsd file? I used this example file from microsoft, and on that one i can right-click go to graph

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xml-tools/sample-xsd-file-simple-schema?view=vs-2022

Can you try adding that to your project and see if you get the option then? That will narrow down if they problem is your file or your VS

Comment: Creating the new xsd file based on Microsoft example i can actually right-click to graph, so the problem is not the IDE or the Project. The main difference is that my xsd file, in the  solution explorer is composed of 4 different files [image](https://imgur.com/a/CDkZAET), because, i think, the xsd file is bound to a SQL datasource.

Comment: Ah interesting. Maybe file a bug report with the VS team? seems like it should work. I dont have a file of that kind so I can't test, sorry I can't help more!